# upload file to storage account using ARM template

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

I am new to azure. I have a storage account created in the azure portal. I need to upload files to the storage account using ARM templates. Can any one please let me know how to do this?

Comment: You can't do that with ARM Templates. Could you give us more details about your requirements?

Comment: I have to move all the created json files in one of the project folder to the storage account. I have to use the ARM template and EV2 tool to do this. I am not sure how to start this. Appreciate any ideas if you have.

Answer (score 1):

As Bruno Faria mentioned that we could not use ARM template to do that. With Azure ARM template. You can deploy, update, or delete all the resources for your solution in a single,coordinated operation. More detail about ARM template please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview)

> With Resource Manager, you can create a template (in JSON format) that defines the infrastructure and configuration of your Azure solution. By using a template, you can **repeatedly deploy** your solution throughout its lifecycle and have confidence your resources are deployed in a consistent state

We could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/) to do that easily.

[image]

If we try to use program to do that we could get the demo code from Azure official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-a-blob-into-a-container).

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Is there any option to do that using azure functions?

Comment: Yes, we also could that with Azure function. we could do that with Azure function Http trigger. But on my opinion, we could upload the file with [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) easily.

Comment: @TomSun As you mentioned is there a way to update existing storage accounts using arm templates such as using our own key to encrypt the storage account etc.. as I have been searching for a while and unable to get anything

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible using `Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts`. Here is an example where I upload a file to a fileshare.

Examples for Bicep. It can easily be converted to:

```
var location = resourceGroup().location
var filename = 'myFile.txt'
var storageaccountname = 'mystorageaccount'
var sharename = 'myfileshare'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: storageaccountname
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }

  resource fileService 'fileServices@2022-05-01' = {
    name: 'default'
    properties: {      
    }

    resource fileShare 'shares@2022-05-01' = {
      name: sharename
      properties: {
        accessTier: 'TransactionOptimized'
        shareQuota: 1
      }
    }
  }
}

resource deploymentScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'upload-cloudflare-warp-config-${storageAccount.name}'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.40.0'
    timeout: 'PT5M'
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H'
    environmentVariables: [
      {
        name: 'AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'
        value: storageAccount.name
      }
      {
        name: 'AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'
        secureValue: storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value
      }
      {
        name: 'CONTENT'
        value: loadTextContent(filename)
      }
    ]
    scriptContent: 'echo "$CONTENT" > ${filename} && az storage file upload --source ${filename} -s ${storageAccount::fileService::fileShare.name}'
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will write your storage key to the deployment script object, which is a security risk.

Comment: Why do we need to use loadTextContent function to first load the file content to a variable, then export the content to another file, and call az storage upload in the end?
I wonder why cannot I call "az storage file upload --source ${filename} -s ${storageAccount::fileService::fileShare.name}" directly?

Answer (score 0):

**Uploading a file to Blob Storage using an ARM Template is currently not supported.**

The logic behind this is that ARM templates are there to manage the Azure Resources (to do actions such as creation, deletion and changing resource properties) and not to manage your usage of these resources.

The ways files can be uploaded to Blob Storage are:

1. **Manually via the Storage Explorer Tool** - [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)
2. **Programatically via the Az Powershell command** -  [az storage blob upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload)

That said, deploying a [Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) container (the Resource itself) can be done as seen in the below template: (credit to [@johndownshere](https://gist.github.com/johndowns))

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "containerName": "logs"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat('default/', variables('containerName'))]",
          "type": "blobServices/containers",
          "apiVersion": "2018-03-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: StorageAccount creation through the ARM template is well documented. The question is asking how to upload a file to a storage account using ARM template, not about storageaccount creation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a dependent [deployment script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#use-existing-storage-account)

Here's an extension of @Aaron M.'s answer. This assumes you're uploading an image, but I'm sure you could modify for other file types.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "containerName": "logs"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat('default/', variables('containerName'))]",
          "type": "blobServices/containers",
          "apiVersion": "2018-03-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
          ]
        },{
          "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
          "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
          "name": "runPowerShellInlineWithOutput",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('default/', variables('containerName'))]"
          ],
          "scriptContent": "
            $b64      = 'AAAAAA...' // Your image in base64
            $filename = 'C:\path\to\file'

            $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
            [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)
            $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName \"[resourceGroup().name]\" -Name \"[parameters('storageAccountName')]\"
            $ctx = $storageAccount.Context 
            $Blob1HT = @{
               File             = $filename
               Container        = [concat('default/', variables('containerName'))]
               Blob             = \"ImageName.jpg\"
               Context          = $ctx
               StandardBlobTier = 'Hot'
            }
            Set-AzStorageBlobContent @Blob1HT
          ",
          "arguments": "[concat('-name', ' ', parameters('name'))]",
          "timeout": "PT1H",
          "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
          "retentionInterval": "P1D"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```